# how to create your own custom ngram filter in solr

Tags: solr

I want to create a custom filter with which i will be able to create ngrams of a query string according to my needs..

How can we create a custom ngram filter for solr-4.10 ???

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need you can [either develop a new filter from scratch](http://solr.pl/en/2012/05/14/developing-your-own-solr-filter/), or you can start [from the existing NGramFilter](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenizer.java) and modify it to suit your needs. The existing NGram and Shingle filters should however be able to do most of what is considered NGrams.

Comment: i already referred to the first link you mentioned which is based on solr 3.6, but i am using solr-4.10.2. In the filter factory code we are extending the BaseTokenFilterFactory, i could not find the class file for BaseTokenFilterFactory in the solr-core. so what should i do..??